# Is it possible to perform like on action on a media using the Instagram API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

There are no endpoints and node for IG like a post.
[image]

I didn't found anything about IG like post.

Comment: It is not possible, they do not provide that functionality via API.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? @CBroe

Comment: no, there is no way. what would be the use case anyway, if i may ask?

Comment: It is simple, I have created an application and I want to like a post from an application
there are multiple posts from multiple platforms. @andyrandy

Comment: that is not really a useful use case, why not just like posts on the platform directly instead?